# How to arrange two divs side by side?

Tags: html, css, visualforce

```
   <div id="buttonpanel" style="display:None; float:left">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!selectQuarter}" value="Go!"  status="actStatusId2"   reRender="pgBlckId,panelrender,panelrender1,panelrender14,panelrender15,panelrender24,panelrender23,panelrender12,panelrender13,panelrender2,panelrender21,panelrender22"  id="button2"/>  
        <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId2" title="This is the status for loading image">
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                 <img src="/img/loading.gif" width="25" height="25" align="bottom" title="Loading"/>
                  <h3> Loading..</h3>           
                </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </div>
```

I want to display these two div tags side by side. Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure i am able see the code completely when in do the edit query.Adding below  <div id="quarterlistpanel" style="display:None; " >
       <apex:selectList id="QuarterSelList" size="1"  title="List of Quartersin year" style=" padding: 2px 4px; margin: 4px 2px;" >
                <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Quarters" itemLabel="Select a Quarter" />
                <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Q1" itemLabel="Quarter 1"/>
                     
            </apex:selectList>
       </div>

Answer (score 0):

I do not see two divs....But changing your h3 elements inside the div to have `inline` display should work as inline elements do not start on a new line.

```
  #buttonpanel h3{
  display:inline;
  }
```